# fill value of input with input value form another field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to fill the input value for host_name with the value that is entered into the first_name and last_name fields so the full name will appear in the host_name field. These fields are on the same page. Jquery or pure JS.

```
<label for="first_name">First Name</label
<input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name">

<label for="last_name">Last Name</label
<input id="last_name" type="text" name="first_name">

<label for="host_name">Host Name</label
<input id="host_name" type="text" name="host_name">
```

Comment: `$("#first_name, #last_name").on("input", function() { $("#host_name").val($("#first_name").val() + " " + $("#last_name").val()); })`.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
let firstName = document.getElementById("first_name");
let lastName = document.getElementById("last_name");
let hostName = document.getElementById("host_name");

firstName.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    hostName.setAttribute("value", event.target.value);
});

lastName.addEventListener("change", (event) => {
    let firstValue = hostName.getAttribute("value");
    let lastValue = event.target.value;
    hostName.setAttribute("value", firstValue + " " + lastValue);
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.